# How to get the sum of Headcount on the footer part without using Union

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

How to get the sum of Headcount on the footer part without using Union .Can anyone give some ideas

```
SELECT DeptID, COUNT(EmpID) AS TotalHeadCount  FROM EmployeeDetails          
WHERE (datepart(yyyy,DOJ) between 2005 and 2017) and Status =0
group by DeptID
Union 
Select Count(EmpID) AS T1 From EmployeeDetails WHERE Status =0`
```

Comment: total is without year condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think your query has some syntactic errors.  Anyway, if grand total has to have the same condtion of partial total (the range of year too), you can use this:
(I simplified the table creating a date_year column, but you can substitute your condition)

```
SELECT DeptID, COUNT(EmpID) AS TotalHeadCount  
FROM EmployeeDetails 
WHERE DATE_YEAR between 2005 and 2017 
    AND STATUS =0 
GROUP BY DEPTID
WITH ROLLUP
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeDetails (EmpID INT, DEPTID INT, DATE_YEAR INT, STATUS INT);
INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES (1,1,2004,0);
INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES (2,1,2005,0);
INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES (3,1,2005,0);
INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES (4,1,2006,0);
INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES (5,1,2007,0);
INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES (5,1,2008,0);
INSERT INTO EmployeeDetails VALUES (6,1,2009,0);
```

Output:

```
DeptID      TotalHeadCount
----------- --------------
1           6
NULL        6
```

Comment: I am using your logic in my below code ,but the total is showing in a diagonal wise

Like This

1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

It shows the value correctly,but take separate columns for each

Comment: @Alston  I added sample data to my answer. I didn't understand your comment above.

Comment: I have posted a query as in answer box please have a look at it SIR

Comment: Actually, that is a new question.  You should post a new one, deciding (or not) to vote for any one of the answer to this question.

Comment: Can I make a make a Name in the 'Null' field

Comment: Some hours ago I did an experiment using COALESCE(DeptID,0) AS DeptID.  I was using 0 for "total" (if you want a string, you need to cast DeptID to varchar).  I think you can do it later, after verify it works.  I think that to make it works, you have to write COALESCE(DeptID,0) AS DeptID in all parts of your new query

Answer (score 0):

How this,

```
SELECT DeptID, COUNT(EmpID) AS TotalHeadCount  FROM EmployeeDetails          
WHERE (datepart(yyyy,DOJ) between 2005 and 2017) and Status =0
group by DeptID WITH CUBE
```